# Is the relative growth rate the same as the derivative.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Context: Recently I have been studying Newton's Law of Cooling, we did a lab the other day and we are now trying to model The temperature of boiling water as it cools down. We collected data every 10 seconds up to 20 minutes. When it came to modelling the function, we simply integrated Newton's Law of Cooling, however, when we were solving for the relative decay rate of the model ( the k in $e^{kx}$) We found that the relative decay rate of the model was not constant, that it changed based on the Temperature and the time.
So in an attempt to solve it, I was wondering, is the relative growth rate the same as the derivative, or in other words, is it correct if I were to try modelling this data using a function of the form,
$$T(t)=Ae^{(r(T_{room}-T))x}$$
Or is in fact the derivative different from the relative growth rate of the function? Or in other words does $k=\frac{dT}{dt}$?

Edit: For added context on how I calculated k. I used the original formula, I have yet to test the mentioned example above. Data is linked here:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mqpnomvey1. Given a point such as $(10, 84.4995168)$, Using substitution into a basic integrated model,
$$T(t)=(T_{0}-T_{room})e^{-kt}+T_{room}$$
Room temperature is 25 Degrees
$$T(t)=(85.125-25)e^{-kt}+25$$
$$84.4995168=60.125e^{-10k}+25$$
$$k=-\frac{1}{10}\ln(\frac{84.4995168-25}{60.125})$$
This was repeated for every data point using excel.

Comment: Please give more details on how you computed $k$. Physical measurements always have some error, did you do an estimate on the error propagation to the computed results? How non-linear does the logarithmic plot look?

Comment: Measurement was done with a sensor, so errors would be very minimal to negligible at best. I plotted the data and k values in Desmos as well: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mqpnomvey1. I will add details to how I calculated k to the question.

Comment: "Relative growth rate" is the derivative of the function divided by the function $ \ \frac{dy/dt}{y} \ \ . $  Exponential functions ("growth" or "decay") have constant relative growth rates.  (So $$ \ \frac{dy}{dt} \ = \ k·y \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ e^{kt} \ \  . \ )  $$

Comment: Then is my choice of model incorrect, (The simple integrated version of Newton's Law of cooling), as it seems that I have a variable relative growth rate given the extra information in the data I added above, you can see that my relative growth rate is variable.

Comment: How sure are you that the room temperature in the immediate neighborhood of the kettle was kept at 25°C? If some buffer close to it increased in temperature, this would slow the cooling.

Comment: Most of my calculations seem to indicate that the temperature was about 25.2 Degrees. The air conditioner was kept on, so temperature can be assumed to be consistent. An alcohol thermometer was used, so I am calculating error propagation with that. I measured the room temperature every 2 minutes, which seemed to converge to about 25 to 25.2 C. However, my main problem right now is how to deal with the fact that K grows smaller as time increases, hence I have no true constant value of k to substitute in my model. Substituting it as a function results in the function not converging to room temp.